# Extract the relevant time from two datasets

Tags: r

I have the following two data-sets

```
dtimes1 = as.POSIXct(c("2002-06-09 12:48:40"))
codes1 = c(110)

df1 <- data.frame(dtimes1, codes1)


dtimes2 = as.POSIXct(c("2002-06-09 12:45:40","2020-01-01 12:49:40", "2020-01-01 12:58:40"))
codes2 = c(100)
call_nr <- c(1,2,3)

df2 <- data.frame(dtimes2, codes2, call_nr)
```

The data in dtimes1 include a particular move during a phone call. In the second data-frame we have the end-timestamp of the phone call.  I am now looking for a piece of code where I can automatically see in which call the event from dtimes1 happened. This would in case be call_2. The output I am looking should give me whole second row.

Any feedback on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `dtimes1`, get the first value in `dtimes2` that is larger.

```
df2$dtimes2[sapply(df1$dtimes1, function(d1) which(df2$dtimes2 > d1)[1])]
#[1] "2020-01-01 12:49:40 PST"
```